# How to get access from inner module (library) to application what include the module?

Tags: java, android, gradle, module, architecture

I am developing an android library(SDK).

Each user (a **partner**) who will use this library should include it like a dependency in a gradle and initialize it with `String partnerId` in his code.

My library has [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) what starts by different device events like [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) etc.
This Service has to have `String partnerId` for correctly working.

The issue:
A play market user, who downloaded partner's application (which includes my library), install it but does not start the application by himself. This means that partner's code does not set `String partnerId` yet, and when a Service will start by some device event it will not has `String partnerId`.

How can I solve the issue? Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have them set their partnerId in the Manifest.xml, perhaps as a meta-data entry. You can then access it via the getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo() call in your Service.